# Segmentation fault after pytest is complete in a github action

Tags: pytest, github-actions

I have a GitHub action where I check out a docker file (of QGIS) installing some requirements and then I run some pytests.

It works great locally but not as a GitHub action, it ends like this:

> ======================== 4 passed, 2 warnings in 5.04s ========================= Segmentation fault (core dumped) Error: Process completed with exit code 139.

I have two projects with similar setup:

- One works: https://github.com/axelande/geodatafarm3/actions/runs/7989077653
- One fails: https://github.com/axelande/OMRAT/actions/runs/7988196096

Any ideas what could cause this error?